# A Formula For Generalized Josephus problem

Tags: reference-request, recursion

There is a formula in wikipedia for the general case of josepus problem

[Josephus Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

But there is no reference for it, I don't know where it came from and I need too find out...
Maybe Donald Knuth's Art of Programming?

Comment: I believe it comes from "Concrete Mathematics"

Answer (score 1):

In "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik. Look in Chapter 3: Integer functions.

Comment: I cannot find it. What is the page for it?